# cmake halts while installing GNU RADIO

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, cmake, arm, gnuradio

I am trying to install GNU Radio in my embedded device (beagle bone with ubuntu 12.04 installation).

After following the instructions from this [Gnuradio install instructions](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/BuildGuide)
page I am stuck at "MAKE".

Since I am using ARM processor :

```
root@omap:/opt/gnuradio/build# cat /proc/cpuinfo
Processor   : ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 274.24
Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x3
CPU part    : 0xc08
CPU revision    : 2

Hardware    : am335xevm
Revision    : 0000
Serial      : 0000000000000000
```

I am doing:

```
# cmake  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING="-mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -g" \

-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING="-mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -g" \

 /opt/gnuradio
```

and this is what I get at the end:

```
-- ######################################################
-- # Gnuradio enabled components                         
-- ######################################################
--   * python-support
--   * testing-support
--   * volk
--   * doxygen
--   * gruel
--   * gnuradio-core
--   * gnuradio-companion
--   * gr-fft
--   * gr-filter
--   * gr-atsc
--   * gr-audio
--   * gr-digital
--   * gr-noaa
--   * gr-pager
--   * gr-qtgui
--   * gr-trellis
--   * gr-utils
--   * gr-video-sdl
--   * gr-vocoder
--   * gr-fcd
--   * gr-wavelet
--   * gr-wxgui
-- 
-- ######################################################
-- # Gnuradio disabled components                        
-- ######################################################
--   * sphinx
--   * gr-comedi
--   * gr-uhd
--   * gr-shd
-- 
-- Using install prefix: /usr/local
-- Building for version: 3.6.2git-117-gf8581fb4 / 3.6.2git
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /opt/gnuradio/build
```

Afterwards when i do make, it gets stuck ..

```
root@omap:/opt/gnuradio/build# make -k
[  1%] Built target volk
[  1%] Built target test_all
[  2%] Built target volk_profile
[  2%] Built target doxygen_target
[  3%] Built target gruel
[  3%] Built target test_gruel
[  3%] Built target _pmt_swig_doc_tag
[  3%] Built target _pmt_swig_swig_tag
[  3%] Built target _pmt_swig
[  3%] Built target pygen_gruel_src_swig_6bac3
[  3%] Built target pygen_gruel_src_python_16cbc
[  4%] Built target pygen_gruel_src_python_319f9
[ 34%] Built target gnuradio-core
[ 34%] Built target gnuradio-config-info
[ 34%] Built target gr_core_rstest
[ 36%] Built target test-gnuradio-core
[ 36%] Built target benchmark_dotprod_ccc
[ 36%] Built target benchmark_dotprod_ccf
[ 36%] Built target benchmark_dotprod_fcc
[ 36%] Built target benchmark_dotprod_fff
[ 36%] Built target benchmark_dotprod_fsf
[ 36%] Built target benchmark_dotprod_scc
[ 36%] Built target benchmark_nco
[ 36%] Built target benchmark_vco
[ 36%] Built target gr_core_test_all
[ 36%] Built target test_filter
[ 36%] Built target test_general
[ 36%] Built target test_runtime
[ 36%] Built target test_vmcircbuf
[ 36%] Built target _filter_swig_doc_tag
[ 36%] Built target _general_swig_doc_tag
[ 36%] Built target _gengen_swig_doc_tag
[ 40%] Built target gengen_generated
[ 40%] Built target filter_generated
[ 40%] Built target _gnuradio_core_filter_swig_tag
[ 41%] Built target _runtime_swig_doc_tag
[ 42%] Built target _gnuradio_core_filter
[ 42%] Built target _gnuradio_core_general_swig_tag
[ 42%] Building CXX object gnuradio-core/src/lib/swig/CMakeFiles  
    /_gnuradio_core_general.dir/gnuradio_core_generalPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
```

at this place and the ram is getting used up completely(256 MB DDR2 RAM). I even had to make a 256 MB linux-swap to avoid the "virtual memory exhausted" error.

Can any one tell me whats going on here and how I can solve this problem .

ps: has any one installed GNU radio on a beagle-bone?

thanks in advance

Sanatan

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `make` without the `-k` option?

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-known problem. There is not enough RAM on your embedded device to actually build GNURadio. GCC is actually running out of memory space, and dying. Your virtual memory space helps, but Swig is a beast.

You have a few options:

1. Cross-compile GNURadio on another system and move the ipkg /
   binary / etc., over to your embedded device.
2. Install GNURadio
   using pre-packaged binary installations (these are available for
   Angstrom - not sure about Ubuntu ARM).
3. Mount your embedded device
   over the network, and cross-compile it from another machine directly
   into the file-system

There are a few others, but those are the options that come to mind immediately.